# Pivot Table by grouping - Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as you see below:

```
    From    Type    To          City    Duration    Value 
    1349    LOCAL   00001111    NW      0:00:30     $ 0,04
    1349    LOCAL   00001111    NW      0:02:18     $ 0,18
    1349    LOCAL   00001111    NW      0:02:36     $ 0,21

    1349    LDN     00009999    CD      0:02:18     $ 0,39
    1349    LDN     00009999    CD      0:02:54     $ 0,49
    1349    MOBILE  00001234    UU      0:02:42     $ 2,03

    1349    MOBILE  00001234    UU      0:03:42     $ 2,78
    1349    MOBILE  00008585    UU      0:00:30     $ 0,75

    4713    MOBILE  00007878    UU      0:01:12     $ 0,90
    4713    MOBILE  00006060    UU      0:00:54     $ 0,68

    4713    LOCAL   00005555    NW      0:01:12     $ 0,10
    4713    LOCAL   00005555    NW      0:03:00     $ 0,24

    4713    LDN     00004646    CD      0:01:42     $ 0,29
    4713    LDN     00004646    CD      0:05:48     $ 0,99
    4713    LDN     00008589    SS      0:02:18     $ 0,39
    4713    LDN     00008589    SS      0:03:12     $ 0,54
```

I need to TOTAL(SUM) the value and show like this way, using group by columns Origin and Type and other TOTAL by origin.

```
    1349    LOCAL   00001111    NW      0:00:30     $ 0,04
    1349    LOCAL   00001111    NW      0:02:18     $ 0,18
    1349    LOCAL   00001111    NW      0:02:36     $ 0,21
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 0,43

    1349    LDN     00009999    CD      0:02:18     $ 0,39
    1349    LDN     00009999    CD      0:02:54     $ 0,49
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 0,88
    1349    MOBILE  00001234    UU      0:02:42     $ 2,03
    1349    MOBILE  00001234    UU      0:03:42     $ 2,78
    1349    MOBILE  00008585    UU      0:00:30     $ 0,75
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 5,56
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 6,87


    4713    MOBILE  00007878    UU      0:01:12     $ 0,90
    4713    MOBILE  00006060    UU      0:00:54     $ 0,68
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 1,58
    4713    LOCAL   00005555    NW      0:01:12     $ 0,10
    4713    LOCAL   00005555    NW      0:03:00     $ 0,24
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 0,34
    4713    LDN     00004646    CD      0:01:42     $ 0,29
    4713    LDN     00004646    CD      0:05:48     $ 0,99
    4713    LDN     00008589    SS      0:02:18     $ 0,39
    4713    LDN     00008589    SS      0:03:12     $ 0,54
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 2,21
    Total:  --------------------------------------->$ 4,13
```

I tried many ways, like

```
print(df.pivot_table( index=['From','Type'] 
                    , columns=[ 'From','Type', 'To', 'City', 'Duration','Value']
                    , margins=True
                    , margins_name='Total'
                    , aggfunc=sum))
```

But I could not find a easy way. I will print the dataframe on PDF using the FPDF lib.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I was asking so I need to put it into another DataFrane. Follow my temp solution.

```
df5 = df.groupby(['From','Type'])
for i,j in df5:
    j.loc['Total'] = j[['CUSTO']].sum()
    print(j)


      Type From          Date  ...       City         Duration  Value
15     LDN   4700  12/05/2020  ...       NW           00:00:36  $ 0.102
16     LDN   4700  12/05/2020  ...       NW           00:02:24  $ 0.408
Total  NaN    NaN         NaN  ...            NaN          NaN  $ 0.510
```

My problem now is when i try to use this values outside the for loop.
If I use df5 instead of "j" I got this error message:

```
    for i,j in df5:
        df5.loc['Total'] = j[['CUSTO']].sum()
```

**AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'loc'**

I just wanna put the total like I have showed up for you after each group From/Type.

Answer (score 0):

I got guys.
To print on pdf I have to iterate each group and print out on pdf.

```
for i,j in df5:
    df5.loc['Total'] = j[['CUSTO']].sum()
    for idx, row in j.iterrows():
```

From this part you only set the pdf properties.
"Easy peasy lemon squeezy" - Now I say that. hahahahaha